# Is this good to follow for counting problems

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, discrete-mathematics

Whenever were doing combinations or permutations, aren’t we always using the product rule? So i can write out the phases for every counting problem and then i determine whether i overcount or not. Usually if its choosing things of the same type, i see that i end up overcounting by the ways you can permute it but if its choosing things that are diff types, like putting caps on different color markers, i am not overcounting because the order in which you choose a cap per colored marker matters.
If this is totally incorrect, which it probably is, how does one know when to overcount or not?

Comment: It seems to me that "counting problems" include more than just what you can solve with combinations or permutations. Presumably you've seen a few examples of counting problems. If you don't change the problem too much, your generalization might apply. Otherwise it wouldn't.

Comment: In particular, the Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion is waiting to blow your mind.

Comment: One relatively general approach to counting is the Twelvefold Way. See https://users.math.msu.edu/users/magyar/Math482/Twelvefold-Way-482.pdf for example. But also see http://proctor.math.unc.edu/30fold.html, claiming another 18 types of counting. And I guess there are counting problems that are not included even in that classification.